# How to get Cash On Deliver Payment >> Case On Delivery Fee using $this->scopeConfig->getValue( ) in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, payment-methods

How can i get the case on delivery fee from cod system config file using scope Config

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject this class in your construct `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`. Use this below code for that :

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
*/
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
  $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function yourFunction() {
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/field', $storeScope);
}
```

Remove generated and clean cache.

[Reference](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-get-store-config-value-in-magento-2/)

Comment: but how can i get the " Cash On Delivery Fee "  field value?

Comment: Cash on Delivery is custom field. I mean created by you. So, can you please upload code for that?

Comment: $array_get['cod'] = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment_method/cash_on_delivery_payment/cash_on_delivery_fee',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

Comment: is this right for get the value

Comment: Yes. But, make sure all ids are perfect.

Comment: or try with this $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/cashondelivery/cash_on_delivery_fee',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112336/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jay-parmar).